# Вертикальный пэйджинг

Tags: android, java

Всем привет, горизонтальную постраничную прокрутку удалось реализовать с помощью `ViewPager`, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли подобный класс для вертикальной прокрутки, можно ли адаптировать  `ViewPager` и как?

Большое спасибо за потраченное время!

Comment: листВью???

Comment: Нет, листвью это же список, без привязки к экрану, мне нужно вертикальное пролистывание экранов. Причем по кругу, если доходишь до последнего элемента, следующим будет первый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гуглить за вас нужно?

[Например это](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager)

Comment: Уже нагуглил такое, до этого разбирался с горизонтальным пэйджингом, тоже нашел подобную библиотеку. А потом http://hashcode.ru/questions/169823/android-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F здесь мне посдказали способ получше, я подумал, возможно, есть аналогичный класс для вертикальной прокрутки.

Спасибо за ответ, в любом случае.

Comment: Собственно, это Вы и были)

Comment: То был стандартный класс SDK. Для вертикальной прокрутки такого нет - насколько я знаю. И решение которое я скинул от одного из самых влиятельных разработчиков библиотек под андроид, так что можете довериться ему, но проверять:)